# Split express app in submodules

Tags: node.js, express

I've this app:

```
// Some modules
var express = require("express");
var ... = require("...");
var ... = require("...");

// Here will go the db
var db;

// Init express
var app = express();

// Express configuration
app.use(...);
app.use(...);

// Routes
app.get("/", function() {});
app.get("/api/v1/a", function() {});
app.get("/api/v1/b", function() {});

// Connect to the db, store it in "db" and then set the port of the app
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/db", function(err, connection) {
  db = connection;
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

I'd like to split this app in multiple files, for example I'd like to move the **api** routes into an `api.js` file.

I've tried with this `api.js`:

```
function(app, db) {
  app.get("/api/v1/a", function() {});
  app.get("/api/v1/b", function() {});
}
module.exports = api;
```

And then use it with:

```
var api = require("./api");
api(app, db);
```

But the routes defined inside it are not executed, how can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found a solution:

**api.js**:

```
module.exports = function (app, db) {
    app.get("/api", function(req, res) { ... });
}
```

**index.js**:

```
require("./api")(app, db);
```

This way it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var api = require("./api");
app.use('/', api)
```